# Finding the horizontal asymptotes $ f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: limits

Find the horizontal asymptotes of the grpah of the function f defined by

$$ f(x) =  \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Solution:

$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}$$
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + 1/x^2}} = 1$$

Okay, the book says the answer is 1 (I skipped the last step).
I'm curious, why did x^2 turn into 1 on the numerator and denominator, and why did the whole fration get a big fraction?
I think I know this somewhere in my head, I need refresher!

Comment: is it $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ or $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: The main important step is that both the top and bottom portions got a multiplier $\frac 1x=\frac1{\sqrt {x^2}}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a few more steps to make it more clear
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}$$
Since $\frac{a^n}{b^n}=\left(\frac ab\right)^n$
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2 +1}}$$
Multiply with $1$
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1/x^2}{1/x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2 +1}}$$
Since $\frac ab\cdot\frac cd=\frac{ac}{bd}$
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + 1/x^2}} = 1$$

Comment: Thank you I don't know how I got confused on that!!

Answer (score 2):

Since detail has already been given for positive $x$, we deal with negative $x$, which have not been mentioned. If $x$ is negative, then $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$. Then the same argument as the one given shows that
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=-1.$$
So $y=-1$ is also a horizontal asymptote.

Another way of seeing this is that $f(x)$ is an **odd** function, meaning that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$, So the graph of $y=f(x)$ for negative $x$ is obtained by rotating the graph for positive $x$ around the origin through $180^\circ$, or equivalently by reflecting in the origin.